# FadeOut finish and then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some issues with my slider. I have colored div (in original project is image) and text on it. All i want is:

1. fadeIn background-color
2. fadeIn text
3. fadeOut Text
4. fadeOut background-color.

Itssounds simply but I cant get this effect. I cant do fadeOut text in time, its suddenly disappear. I tried add anonymous funcion in fadeOut() and it didnt works.

```
<section class="opinions">
    <div class="opinionsContent"> 
        <div class="slider">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/jes6vhdf/

Comment: I would recommend using CSS to handle all your transitions and fades. Just use Jquery to add and remove classes.

Comment: I tried add transition to 60 line of jsFiddle scss code, but it dosent works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with fadeOut callback :

**Javascript**

```
    $('.opinions .slider').removeClass(sliderBGClasses[currentClass]);
    $('.opinions .slider h2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).removeClass(descriptionsClasses[currentClass]);
        currentClass = currentClass + 1 < descriptionsClasses.length ? currentClass + 1 : 0;
        $('.opinions .slider h2').fadeIn('slow').addClass(descriptionsClasses[currentClass]);
        $('.opinions .slider').addClass(sliderBGClasses[currentClass]);
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jes6vhdf/1/)

Comment: Its strange because it works well on jsFiddle, but not in my main project.